# What Adobe License do I need as an Individual that sells designs?

Tags: business, licensing

I want to do Photoshop design work, and sell designs to people.
I don't have much money right now to invest in Photoshop, but I'm definitely thinking of saving up to whatever amount that is required (within reason of course)

I don't need more than one license, because it is just me.

Which plan is correct for this? Do I need a Business plan or Individual plan for doing Commercial Work? I've been searching online and I couldn't find a proper answer that fits right to my case.

I'm willing to hear about any version, if you know the prices, that would be great. just need the plan to fit to my intentions.

Comment: If it's possible, I'd skip the "subscription" model of Adobe entirely and look at Gimp, Pixelmator, or other options if you're just starting out. Adobe's pricing and customer service just continually gets worse. You'd be better served by avoiding Adobe if you can. This posted by a long time Adobe user.

Comment: I'm not a starter. I dealt with photoshop for 3 years in the military and before. I want to start my own art salesment. is CC bad?

Comment: The apps aren't bad at all.. it's the pricing model I'd avoid if possible. The "Pay us monthly or you can't access that file you created a year ago." bothers me greatly. I Have CC, and CC 2014.. but I still work mostly in CS6 due to this.

Comment: If you have to work with other design firms, PhotoShop is important as it's the 'common language'. However, if you don't, I agree with Scott. There are lots of options out there that cost a lot less.

Comment: Paying $10 a month for the license is fair in my opinion. im still questioning myself if im allowed to sell art. Scott, what do you mean by can't access? the PSD files are not saved on your local machine? can I not access them from anywhere else? you say you're using CS6. where did you buy it and what would be the price nowdays? Thanks

Comment: I've found CS6 for $700 on their website. couldnt find the right details im looking for. is this +/- the price for it?

Comment: Yes. $699 is the perpetual license price for non-cloud version of CS6. You can also shop around (be careful, though, who you buy from) for older versions that are on sale on eBay and elsewhere.

Comment: Here's how to not worry about being able to open your files: Let's say you were so unsuccessful that you sold nothing and couldn't afford the $10 a month so that your subscription expired. A year goes by, and suddenly someone wants to buy a piece of your art if you'll modify it a bit. You sign up for a free trial with a new Adobe ID, download and use Photoshop to make the edits. There is no practical way for you to be locked out of your files, ever. The way Adobe set it up makes sure of that.

Comment: @AlanGilbertson, that probably violates their Terms of Service.  Setting up multiple IDs, particularly multiple IDs to avoid free trial expiration, is usually a no-go legally.  Do you have any evidence to the contrary?

Comment: @Scott, while this is fair, if you've *created* the file one would assume you've exported it as a PDF as well, right?  You can still access the *PDF* version of your old files, can't you?  (And you would need to pay to open up InDesign and edit the file, but that's *editing*, not just access/viewing.)

Comment: @Scott, I have CS6 but only on my old Mac (running 10.7.4).  From what I read it won't run on El Capitan, though I haven't actually tried installing it.  If I could transition CS6 to the new computer I would probably skip CC.

Answer (score 3):

I would go with a Creative Cloud subscription. Take a look.

https://creative.adobe.com/en/plans

I have a Complete one, because I use more than one of their applications and I have steady clients that justify the monthly expense, but if you need only PS, then it looks like 9.99 would do the trick.

**Will my files be hosted on their servers?**

No. You can host them in your own station.

**Can I buy a personal subscription and use it for business?**

I believe so. The business subscription is designed to help businesses to save money. It is like buying in bulk. This does not mean that you cannot use the personal ones for business. I have a personal one and use it solely for business. My main client has 4 designers in house and has a personal license for each one of them instead of a business one.

**Are you sure sure sure I can use it for business?**

No, I am not. I am not a legal adviser : ) I am using it for business, though, so at some point I guess I did the research. I can't find anywhere in the web where it explicitly says so. Something you could do, though, is to try to buy a personal license. In the process, you will be presented with the legal terms and you will have to agree to them before proceeding to paying. You can give them a thorough read. I would think (don't take my word) that if it does not say explicitly that you can't use it for business, you can. It would be like renting a camera. You can use it for whatever you want unless they told you you can't use it for business and you agreed to it.

Comment: The only licenses that have a 'commercial work' restriction are the educational licenses.

Comment: What DA01 said. The only difference between Business and Individual is extra cloud and management tools. You need individual.

Comment: Sounds good then. am i blocked from anything else? is the cloud extra space is optional and not really needed? also, are there any websites nowdays that sells the CS6 version? im not a student. I just want to work with it and basicly do whatever I want with my photoshop.

Comment: @user26221, yes, you can still get CS6, and *don't* get it from a fishy third-party vendor; you are likely to get burned.  Here is [the only remaining official source for Photoshop CS6](http://www.adobe.com/products/cs6.html), according to [this article](https://blog.conradchavez.com/2016/01/06/can-you-buy-adobe-software-without-a-subscription/).

Answer (score 1):

The license granted you by Adobe permits you to use the software. It places no restrictions on whether you can use it for commercial or non-commercial purposes, much in the same way that a set of carpenters tools don't come with restrictions on whether you can sell what you make.

Comment: Gotcha. I might purchase the plan for the $10 a month this week.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a bit late now but I found this...

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1271552

In short, I get the impression that the adobe staff don't care. They offer the different licenses for the sake of different perks.

It doesn't seem like there's any legal consequence of using 1 over the other, with the exception of license ownership.

e.g. the individual license is owned by the individual using the software, whereas the business license is owned by the business regardless of who is using it.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution and welcome to GraphicDesign! Let us know if you have any questions